# Changing margin of a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I'm making a webpage that contains a picture gallery. I've written a javascript function to display a larger version of an image when you click on the miniature. What the function does is that it changes the search path of an img tag within a div that is hidden. It then changes the top and left values of the div to position the div in the center of the screen and then it's supposed to adjust the top and left margin of the div depending on the image size to place its middle in the center of the screen.

This is where it fails. Or really, it works, but not when it's supposed to. If I open an image for the first time it has the wrong offset from the center (the negative margins for top and left are wrong). If I open it again however, it works! I get the same error if I open an image with a different width and height.

This is the code used to set the margins:

```
    imagebox.style.marginLeft=(image.width/-2)+'px';
    imagebox.style.marginTop=(image.height/-2)+'px';
```

This works just fine in google chrome and and in safari, but in other browsers it doesn't always use this code and sometimes it gives it a double call.

And in the end I of course set the div visibility to visible.

Comment: Open an image the first time to get the error. Then zoom the page in and out (Ctrl+mousewheel works for this, or Ctrl++ and Ctrl+-). If the margins "magically" fix themselves, then it's a common redraw error. If not, then we can look further into code errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the jQuery functions `.css()` and `.width()`/`.height()`. They work fine in almost every browser.

Comment: I did this and it didn't solve my problem (but it made my code a whole lot simpler though, using jQuery). However, I solved it with a hover event on the miniature image to move the container for the larger image before the click event.